# How to specify height and width using react-drag-drop-file?

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I'm using [react-drag-drop-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-drag-drop-files) package for file upload on my website, however I don't see any options on how to specify height and width in the documentation. Currently the object looks like this, but I want to make it taller.

[image]

Is there a way to do so or do I have to use a different package for file uploads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `classes` prop and add a class to the component and then use that class to style the component with `css`.

```
  <FileUploader
    classes="custom-fileUploader"
    multiple={true}
    handleChange={handleChange}
    name="file"
    types={fileTypes}
  />
```

Now just give `.custom-fileUploader` the `height` (and any other style) you want and make the component taller.